# How to style tag inside all portlet instances?

Tags: css, liferay, portlet

How to select all portlet instances with CSS, not single instance? On my page I see outermost portlet tag as

```
<div id="p_p_id_promotion_WAR_promotionportlet_INSTANCE_mxMxCb1CjaeA_" class="portlet-boundary portlet-boundary_promotion_WAR_promotionportlet_ promotion-portlet  portlet-draggable yui3-dd-drop">
```

i.e. it is tagged by instance. So I can select bu id `p_p_id_promotion_WAR_promotionportlet_INSTANCE_mxMxCb1CjaeA_` because this id is specific for instance. I see no ids specific to all portlets of this plugin.

Are styles inside `main.css` applied to all page or portlet content only?

Answer (score 0):

The property file `liferay-portlet.xml` provide entry

`<css-class-wrapper>XYZ</css-class-wrapper>`

This CSS class [here:XYZ] will be injected in the DIV-element that wraps the portlet. And hence you can provide this class as prefix to your css rules to apply at for those portlet on any page.

HTH